# Can I add fonts to dompdf in CiviCRM?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to print pdf thank you letters in Garamond font and I am having problems figuring out how to add fonts to dompdf.

Does anyone know if this is the right approach?  If so, had anyone added fonts before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone else is looking for the answer to this please look at the documentation here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/unicode_pdf/

Also see this answer:

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/27746/127