# Special Characters Become Question Marks "?" in PDF Printing

Tags: pdf, invoice

-I'm using Civicrm 5.11.0, Joomla 3.8.0, Windows 7
-SQL is encode in utf8
-Chinese characters in phpmysql are readable
-Chinese characters in Civicrm are readable
-Civicrm saves data in utf8, so import or export contacts in Chinese is fine
-CiviMail can send email with Chinese characters
-Win 7 can read Chinese characters and save word documents in pdf as Chinese
-but when I go to Individual>Contribution>Print Invoice as PDF, they all turn to question marks (one character, one question mark)
-put Chinese characters in invoice templates, turns to question marks too

I tried to change this code

```
   $dompdf->load_html( $html );
```

to this

```
   $dompdf->load_html( utf8_decode( $html ) );
```

(from ../civicrm/CRM/Utils/PDF/Utils.php)

but nothing happened, still question marks.
What could be the cause of this?

I also tried this on demo site, same results display.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Might be similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/how-to-change-the-encoding-in-pdf-documents

Comment: this works! Thank you! You saved my day again Demerit!

Comment: This has been raised as an issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOMPDF in CiviCRM have a trouble with special characters UTF-8. We have this same problem in Poland. I've create a repo with solution: https://github.com/ngo360/civicrm.dompdf.utf8

For apply this change go to path: path/to/civicrm/vendor/dompdf and delete all files. Then upload files from repo. I think is resolve Your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering do you still need to edit print.css as described at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/how-to-change-the-encoding-in-pdf-documents or does this always enforce dejavu?

Comment: I only change this files - its works well. I don't make any changes in print.css It's simple pack for fix this issue. :)

Comment: Ok upon examine again on dompdf\lib\fonts folder i noticed there was a ufm ,ufm.php and afm files generated for simsun, but it's named with some random numbers. So I changed those names to simsun, removed the @font code in print.css, rename the number font name represent as simsun in dompdf_font_family_cache.php, now it's working nice and clean!

Comment: Hi Jennifer - how did you get simsun font into the dompdf\lib\fonts folder? Where did you download it from? -- KarinG